# Node fs.writeFile not working with template literals / strings

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a script that uses the Chrome Lighthouse package to return performance metrics about a page. It returns the HTML as a string.

When I specify to `fs.writeFile` a standard string without template literals, it writes the output to the file as expected. E.g.

```js
  for (let config of lhConfigs) {
    const runnerResult = await launchLighthouse(chromeFlags, options, config);
    const outputFileName = 'lh_report.html';
    fs.writeFile(outputFileName, runnerResult, (err) => {
      if (err) console.error(err);
      else console.log("successfully wrote to file");
    });
```

Successfully creates a file called `lh_report.html` in the directory, with the content of the Lighthouse report.

But I need filenames to be unique, so I attempted to use template literals:

```js
  for (let config of lhConfigs) {
    const runnerResult = await launchLighthouse(chromeFlags, options, config);
    const currentTime = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 16);
    const outputFileName = `lh_report_${currentTime}.html`;
    fs.writeFile(outputFileName, runnerResult, (err) => {
      if (err) console.error(err);
      else console.log("successfully wrote to file");
    });
```

This creates an **empty** file named `lh_report_2021-12-23T18`, it also is missing the `.html` extension. I've confirmed that `runnerResult` is not null / empty using the debugger. I'm not sure why using a template string seems to break the functionality?

Node 14.17.0

Comment: @derpirscher The filename is not always the same, each of the configs also has a formFactor variable, e.g. const { formFactor } = config.settings;. So the filename is actually `const outputFileName = `lh_report_${formFactor}_${currentTime}.html`;` Changing `fs.writefile` to `await fsPromises.writeFile(outputFileName, runnerResult);` doesn't affect it at all, unless you mean something else by awaiting the filewriting?

Comment: Of course `await fs.writeFile` won't change anything, because the default form of `fs.writeFile` doesn't return a promise. You need `fs.promises.writeFile` to make it `await`able ... Furthermore, you should post the exact code that causes the problem. Even if you notice problems with your filewriting, I'm absolute certain, it has nothing to do with the filename being a template string, but just with the characters in the filename. If you say, the file is named `...18` and missing the `:01.html` part, that could be a hint, that `:` is not allowed in a filename?

Comment: And the explanaition why your file is empty but there is no error throws can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_stream_(ADS)  Ie something like `foo:bar` is in prinicple perfectly legal, but leads to results you are probably not expecting ...

Comment: @derpirscher `await fsPromises.writeFile(outputFileName, runnerResult);` is what I wrote in my comment, I am using fsPromises :)

But you were right, it's the colon in the filename from the Date. The filename gets cut off right where the colon is. Thank you for pointing that out and your patience, if you want to submit as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see the `promise` there, my bad ...